# How to install TheRubyRacer for Windows (libv8)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, windows-10, therubyracer

This is the CMD log from when I was installing BeEF in order to test something on my Phone

---

C:\Ruby22\BeEF>gem install therubyracer -v 0.11.3
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160208-15524-46e9ed.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... no
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:

```
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby22/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
    --with-v8-dir
    --without-v8-dir
    --with-v8-include
    --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
    --with-v8-lib
    --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib
```

C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': You have chosen to use the version of V8 found on your system (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
and *not* the one that is bundle with the libv8 rubygem. However,
it could not be located. please make sure you have a version of
v8 that is compatible with 3.11.8.17 installed. You may
need to special --with-v8-dir options if it is in a non-standard
location

thanks,
The Mgmt

```
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
    from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'
```

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/therubyracer-0.11.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/therubyracer-0.11.3/gem_make.out

C:\Ruby22\BeEF>gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.11.3'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command therubyracer,

### C:\Ruby22\BeEF>

### ---------------------------------------------------------------

Anyone know how to correctly install this Gem?

I'm on Windows 10 x32 Bit, btw